# how to use Servlet along with hostname in JAVA HTTP POST using builder class

Tags: java, http, builder

I am trying to build a http POST in Java with builder class and can't figure out how to combine servlet with hostname. Tried to find some examples on this but couldn't.

```
private static String HOSTNAME = "servlet.nuancemobility.net";
private static String SERVLET = "/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation";
```

And the builder class I am using:

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("https");
    builder.setHost(HOSTNAME);
    builder.addParameter(SERVLET, SERVLET);
    builder.setPort(443);
    builder.build();
    return builder;
```

The URl should look like this: `https://servlet.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation`

but with

```
builder.addParameter(SERVLET, SERVLET);
```

it looks like this:

```
https://servlet.nuancemobility.net:443?%2FNMDPAsrCmdServlet%2Fdictation=%2FNMDPAsrCmdServlet%2Fdictation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The /NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation portion of the URL is the path to the servlet resource, not a parameter.  Try using:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("https");
    builder.setHost(HOSTNAME);
    builder.setPath(SERVLET);   
    builder.setPort(443);
    builder.build();
    return builder;
```

The parameter list is for parameters (name/value pairs) added to the query string.